# How would I cite a presentation given at a press conference with BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

How would I cite a presentation given at a press conference with BibTeX?
For example this one https://www.danskebank.com/en-uk/ir/Documents/2015/Q4/PresentationQ42015-Press.pdf

Comment: Is this question really on-topic here? And isn't it primarily opinion-based?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is primarily opinion-based, but probably you should use `@ONLINE` (depends on `biblatex` or `bibtex` and the style) or `@MISC` for that purpose.

```
@online{results,
author = {{Danske Bank}},
title = {Financial results for 2015},
url = {https://www.danskebank.com/en-uk/ir/Documents/2015/Q4/PresentationQ42015-Press.pdf},
organization = {Danske Bank},
date = {2016-02-02},
urldate = {2017-03-04}
}

@Misc{results,
author = {{Danske Bank}},
title = {Financial results for 2015},
howpublished = {\textsc{url:}~\url{https://www.danskebank.com/en-uk/ir/Documents/2015/Q4/PresentationQ42015-Press.pdf}},
month = {2},
year = {2016}
}
```

Comment: Mhh, `year = {2002},` and `month = {2},` seem to contradict `date = {2016-02-02},`. With `biblatex`, `date` alone is to be preferred.

Comment: @moewe You're fully correct, I've just inserted those information into a Texmaker template. Bad decision.