# How can I cite something with Biblatex style=apa so that the complete date appears after the author's name?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I just learned that APA citations require that after a government press briefing the full date be named. See here: https://www.easybib.com/guides/how-to-cite-a-white-house-press-briefing/

I followed the instructions here [How would I cite a presentation given at a press conference with BibTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356870/how-would-i-cite-a-presentation-given-at-a-press-conference-with-bibtex) but the resulting citations will only print the year, not the complete date.

How do I need to format the citations so that they appear with the full name?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about the citation (the label in the text) or about the bibliography at the end. If I take the Danske Bank's `results` example from your second link I get the full date in the bibliography, but only the year in citations. I believe this is the expected output for APA. If you think otherwise, please double check with the APA manual and report this issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues

Comment: (I'm talking APA style 6th ed.!) Both https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/10/how-to-cite-social-media-in-apa-style.html and https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/09/how-to-cite-a-press-release-in-apa-style.html have examples with full dates in the bibliography but year only in citations. I have yet to come a across an example with full dates in citations (except personal communication).

Comment: The outcome that I am looking for is as you and the APA manual describe it. But when I enter the `date` field, it doesn't show up. Which kind of citation style do I need to use for such a government publication? Article? Online?

Comment: I typed up a quick answer, if that doesn't work for you, we need to see what you are doing. The easiest way to show us that is via a short example document like the one in my answer, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864. It should tell us about the relevant packages you load and what your `.bib` entry looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the *Danske Bank* example from [TeXnician](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/124577/texnician)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356895/35864) to the linked question

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{danskebank:results2015,
  author       = {{Danske Bank}},
  title        = {Financial results for 2015},
  url          = {https://www.danskebank.com/en-uk/ir/Documents/2015/Q4/PresentationQ42015-Press.pdf},
  date         = {2016-02-02},
  urldate      = {2017-03-04}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{danskebank:results2015}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

we obtain

[image: Danske Bank, 2016//Danske Bank. (2016, February 2). Financial results for 2015. Retrieved March 4, 2017, from https://www.danskebank.com/en-uk/ir/Documents/2015/Q4/PresentationQ42015-Press.pdf]

Depend on the exact form of publication `@misc` and `@online` seem like the obvious choices. In some cases `@unpublished` might be an alternative, in some case `@book`. But this is a decision that will have to be made knowing more about the exact details of the source you intend to cite. `@article` is rarely the right choice for sources like this unless they were actually published in a (scholarly) journal (or a newspaper).

As far as I can tell this is in line with 6th-ed. APA style, see for example https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/10/how-to-cite-social-media-in-apa-style.html and https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/09/how-to-cite-a-press-release-in-apa-style.html. (The 7th edition only just came out and at the moment `biblatex-apa` still implements 6th-edition APA style.)

Comment: Unfortunately, when I use these specifications, I end up with a citation that only mentions the year, not the complete date. The line I use to implement biblatex looks like this: `\usepackage[style=apa, natbib=true,backend=bibtex,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}`  For reasons unbeknownst to me I need to set `natbib=true` and `sorting=nyt`, otherwise not all references are shown in-text or in the bibliography. I can therefore not test whether these two setting are the culprit. Do you think they might be?

Comment: @TeaTree Yes that is a problem, when I run my example with `backend=bibtex` I get the error message `! Package biblatex Error: Biber backend is required by style.` and don't obtain the expected output. If you want to use `biblatex-apa`, you must switch to using Biber, you can not use BibTeX. On a modern system switching to Biber should be as easy as writing `backend=biber` in the options and running Biber instead of BibTeX on your file (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on configuring your editor for Biber).

Comment: This worked! I wasn't aware that biblatex-apa depends on biber. Thanks so much!